# When I try to login with twitter I am facing ”Unable to process request due to missing initial state". in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase, twitter, twitter-oauth

When I try to login using twitter I am facing ”Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared” even though I have configured app in Twitter Developer portal and set it to Firebase and I also defined schema in the App.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa9ey.png)

I have tried sign in with twitter functionality in my app. I have also tried by adding callback URL in twitter developer portal, but I didn't succeed please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are affected with this session storage issue with only twitter but other platform works well, Make sure you read the documentation properly from [https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social] (twitter section)

and also if the code implementation doesnt work from flutterfire docs use the snippet below

```
    import 'package:flutter_facebook_auth/flutter_facebook_auth.dart';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future<void> _signInWithTwitter() async {
  TwitterAuthProvider twitterProvider = TwitterAuthProvider();

  if (kIsWeb) {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(twitterProvider);
  } else {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(twitterProvider);
  }
}
```

Note: make sure read the docs